# Prevent PIN_Backtrace() Unsuccessful Exit

Tags: linux, trace, backtrace, intel-pin, libunwind

I have a pintool that has calls to `PIN_Backtrace()`. It seems that `libunwind` does not support some registers in `x86_64` and this leads to the following error message and an abnormal exit:

```
libunwind: uint64_t libunwind::Registers_x86_64::getRegister(int) const Source/bionic/libunwind/src/Registers.hpp:342 - unsupported x86_64 register
Aborted
```

I want the program to continue even with these errors. What is the most efficient way to handle this situation?

I debugged my `pintool` using `gdb`. Here is the backtrace when `abort()` is received by the debugger:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff726c22b in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fffeca88730 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007ffff726c363 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000005386 in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

`info proc mapping` shows the address ranges as follows:

```
...
0x7fffeea3a000     0x7ffff71fb000  0x87c1000        0x0 
0x7ffff71fb000     0x7ffff7283000    0x88000        0x0 /home/ahmad/Programs/pin-3.7-97619-g0d0c92f4f-gcc-linux/intel64/runtime/pincrt/libc-dynamic.so
0x7ffff7283000     0x7ffff7284000     0x1000        0x0 
0x7ffff7284000     0x7ffff7286000     0x2000    0x88000 /home/ahmad/Programs/pin-3.7-97619-g0d0c92f4f-gcc-linux/intel64/runtime/pincrt/libc-dynamic.so
...
```

and

```
...
0x7fffe1687000     0x7fffec287000  0xac00000        0x0 
0x7fffec287000     0x7fffed28e000  0x1007000        0x0 
0x7fffed28e000     0x7fffedb6a000   0x8dc000        0x0 
...
```

It seems that the `libunwind` library used by `Pin` is a special one exlusive to `PinCRT`. This can be seen in the `info /proc/<PID>/maps` output for the `pintool`:

```
...
7ffff7e33000-7ffff7e45000 r-xp 00000000 08:13 466277                     /home/ahmad/Programs/pin-3.7-97619-g0d0c92f4f-gcc-linux/intel64/runtime/pincrt/libunwind-dynamic.so
7ffff7e45000-7ffff7e46000 r--p 00011000 08:13 466277                     /home/ahmad/Programs/pin-3.7-97619-g0d0c92f4f-gcc-linux/intel64/runtime/pincrt/libunwind-dynamic.so
7ffff7e46000-7ffff7e47000 rw-p 00012000 08:13 466277                     /home/ahmad/Programs/pin-3.7-97619-g0d0c92f4f-gcc-linux/intel64/runtime/pincrt/libunwind-dynamic.so
...
```

Comment: Your libunwind calls `abort()` in the process of executing code. Fastest way to continue execution is to comment out  _LIBUNWIND_ABORT line in `inline uint32_t Registers_x86::getRegister` function: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libunwind/blob/master/src/Registers.hpp#L123 (replace with something like `return -1`). Better way is to recompile pin and libunwind with debugging information and to use debugger to get backtrace and find who did call getRegister and what arguments were passed into it. Your question now is incomplete and hard to reproduce, versions and compile strings are not listed.

Comment: Thanks! So I should compile `libunwind` from source and uninstall the one provided as **Ubuntu package**. To provide more precise information I need to recompile `Pin`. But the source is not available for `pinbin`. I have the debuginfo for my `pintool` and `libunwind`. I updated the question with the backtrace provided by `sudo gdb ../../../intel64/bin/pinbin`.

Comment: To get backtrace you can just install libunwind debug package (dbgsym - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libunwind); to quick fix the abort you should recompile libunwind (with apt-get source libunwind; editing and then dpkg buildpackage). Not needed (not safe) to replace libunwind globally, you can try to use custom version with LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable set to directory with your lib. Your backtrace now have no any useful data.

Comment: Well, I will recompile that. But the backtrace has nothing in the `libunwind` address range. It seems that the `libunwind` used by `Pin` is a special library exlusive to `PinCRT`. Please, have a look at the updated question.